# How to calculate $p$ value bound for $\chi^2$ test

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a hypothesis test concerning the variance from a normal population with $H_0: \sigma_2=339.7$ and $H_a: \sigma_2<339.7$. Select bounds on the $p$ value for $n=11$ and test statistic $\chi^2=1.36$.

A) $0.025\leq p\leq0.05$

B) $0.0001\leq p\leq 0.001$

C) $p\leq 0.0001$

D) $0.005\leq p\leq 0.01$

Comment: Do you know how to find the degrees of freedom?

Comment: @Big Agnes, d.f = n -1 = 10

Comment: Right, so you're looking for $P(\chi^2 < 1.36| df = 10)$. i.e. the lower tail probability. Based on the fact that the question asks for a range, I assume you are using a table of values.

Comment: @Big Agnes, so I can see that x2 : 2.16 for 0.995 and our chi square value is :1.36 , so p value will be 1-0.995 =0.005 for left tail test?

Comment: So, option D  correct?

Comment: You should look at your options again. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure the rational and computations are clear:

To test $H_0: \sigma = 339.7$ against $H_a: \sigma < 339.7,$
one uses the test statistic
$$Q_{obs} = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma_0^2},$$
where $S$ is the sample standard deviation of your normal
sample of size $n = 11$ and $\sigma_0 = 339.7.$ 
You do not give the numerical value of the sample SD $S,$ but
you report that $Q_{obs} = 1.36.$

You would reject $H_0$ when $Q_{obs}$ is sufficiently small.
In your case that would be when $S$ is 'significantly' smaller than
the null value $333.7.$

Under $H_0$ (that is, assuming $H_0$ to be true), 
$$Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$$

At the fixed significance level $\alpha =0.01 = 1\%,$ you would
reject $H_0$ if $Q_{obs} < q^*,$ where one sees from printed tables
or software that the 'critical value' $q^* = 2.558$ cuts 1% of the
probability from the lower tail of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(10),$
the chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu = n -1 = 11 - 1 = 10.$
This distribution has mean $E(Q) = \nu = 10.$ Because $Q_{obs} = 1.35 < 2.558$
you would reject $H_0$ at the 1% level of significance.

From R statistical software,

```
qchisq(.01, 10)
## 2.558212
```

The P-value is the probability under $H_0$ of getting a value of $Q < Q_{obs}.$
In general, one cannot find the exact P-value using tables of the chi-squared
distribution because not enough probabilities and critical values are given.
In your specific case, the P-value from R is 0.00069, which is between
the values 0.0001 and 0.001 in one of your answers.

```
pchisq(1.36, 10)
## 0.0006907683
```

Presumably your chi-squared table shows critical values close to
0.8889 and 1.4787, which 'bracket' 1.36.

```
qchisq(c(.0001, .001), 10)
## 0.8889204 1.4787435
```

The figure below shows the density curve for $\mathsf{Chisq}(10)$ with a
solid vertical black line at $Q_{obs}=1.36.$ The dashed vertical red line
cuts 1% of the area from the lower tail of the curve. The two dotted brown
lines are at the values mentioned above that bracket your observed value 1.36.

[image]

Comment: oh I see, got it thanks a lot.